# what does the 'e' in this javascript code do?

Tags: javascript

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e)
    validateInput()
```

I don't know what the 'e' inside the function does. I'm taking classes and I missed some, it's midnight and my instructor is unavailable atm to answer my question

Comment: It is a function parameter. It can be named anything, but people use `e` to mean event, since that is what the listener passes to it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 2):

In this case, we get an event as the first argument of the handler function to submit, which we can name as we like (because it is a parameter)

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event

Comment: okay, how about validateInput( ) and  preventDefault( ), are they javascript functions or they were named too?

Comment: Follow the link to get the answers to those questions.

Comment: @tokonimichael these are methods of the Event class. For example, preventDefault prevents the standard behavior, cancels the redirect for the link, and changes the status for the checkbox.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: @tokonimichael @SlavaDodonov `validateInput()` is not a method of `Event`.

Comment: @InSync sorry, I didn’t check this info. I wrote only about preventDefault